# Batch-creation of Alfresco users

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to create [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) users in a "batch" way?
I mean, creating lots of users with a script or calling an API or something.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a module for the Share admin console in the Share-Extras project which allows the creation of users from a CSV file. It can found here: http://code.google.com/p/share-extras/wiki/CreateBulkUsers

Comment: There is also another way to create users programatically using the Javascript API which I have detailed in a blog post: http://www.techbits.de/2011/12/02/using-the-javascript-console-creating-users-with-avatar-images/

Answer (score 1):

The alfresco shell tools project allows the batch creation of Alfresco users:

https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-shell-tools/wiki/UsersAndGroupsFun#Create_a_new_user

It wraps the REST APIs mentioned in the other replies in an easy to use manner.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do that is to use the addPerson webscript.
Just create a small application that calls the webscript (it's a normal HTTP POST request) with the user data you want.

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Add_Person

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Alfresco Team, or a recent nightly build, then you can simply upload a CSV / Excel file of users and have them created for you. (It's in Swift too)

You'll find the link to do this in the admin console, and the webscript that backs this is http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/people/upload (perform a GET to fetch the spreadsheet template, or a POST to upload the users)